# How to create react native project

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm new to the react native platform. I'd like to create an app with bottom, stack, and drawer navigation.
I'm not sure which navigation is appropriate for the same react navigation (v4, v5, or v6).

I'd also like to make some API calls. Is it necessary to use redux for this?

Is it better to use React native element or react native paper for ui design?

Please, someone assist me with this.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seems to be an appropriate question to ask here, you can go through their official documentations, some courses maybe to learn react-native and its best practices. As for the questions you have asked, since you are learning react native now,

1. Go with the latest navigation ([v6](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started))
2. It's always a good practice to use [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) for api calls.
3. For UI, you can go with any library that suites your purpose, it does not have to be one, you can use multiple, based on what you want to achieve.